# Delete (or not insert) the new row in a trgger

Tags: triggers, insert, db2

I use DB2 Express-C.
I have ON INSERT trigger on a table, where I insert the new row into another table. 
Is there a way not to insert the new row into the table on which the trigger is defined?

Any help is appreciated, thank you

Comment: Are you asking how you can avoid having the trigger fire on insert?

Comment: Yes, exactly, on a table

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [create trigger](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/index.jsp) and the INSTEAD OF option:

> Specifies that the associated triggered action replaces the action
>   against the subject view. Only one INSTEAD OF trigger is allowed for
>   each kind of operation on a given subject view (SQLSTATE 428FP).

Answer (score 0):

Typically something like this can be done by evaluating whether a special register (e.g., `CURRENT USER`) has a particular value.

```
create trigger trigger1
    after insert on schema.table
    referencing new as n
    for each row
    when (CURRENT USER <> 'NAMSARAY')
       insert into schema.tablecopy values (n.c1, n.c2, ...);
```

If you are on DB2 9.7 or later, you could also consider defining a variable and using that variable as a control of whether or not the trigger will perform its action.

```
create variable schema.var1 smallint default 0;
```

Then you can check the value of this variable in the trigger.  Unless an application has explicitly set the variable to a predetermined value (-9999 in the example below), the trigger will fire:

```
create trigger trigger2
    after insert on schema.table
    referencing new as n
    for each row
    when (schema.var1 <> -9999)
       insert into schema.tablecopy values (n.c1, n.c2, ...);
```